# Foreign key to a group of attributes given as primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a `Class` table with the primary keys as `Section`, `Semester` and `Department`. Another `Student` table with a `USN` as the primary key. First why does it allow me to reference `Class.Semester` from  `Student.SEM`? Shouldn't I only be allowed to reference the primary key in `Class` from a group of attributes as foreign key in the `Student`? I also tried to reference `Class.section` from `Student.Class` and I get an error saying `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint`.

```
CREATE TABLE `Class` (
  `Semester` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `Section` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `Department` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `CTID` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Class`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Semester`,`Section`,`Department`);

CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `USN` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `DOB` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Class` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `SEM` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `Dep` varchar(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

ALTER TABLE `student`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`USN`),
  ADD KEY `Class` (`Class`,`SEM`,`Dep`),
  ADD KEY `SEM` (`SEM`);

ALTER TABLE `student`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `student_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SEM`) REFERENCES `Class` (`Semester`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL supports a smaller number of columns from the available keys as long as the list of columns starts with the list of columns in the key, as described in [13.1.17.6 Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> - MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. **In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order**. Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint. index_name, if given, is used as described previously.
> - InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any column or group of columns. **However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order**.

So in your case you can use the column `Semester` because it's the start of your index `(Semester, Section, Department)`, but you cannot use `Section` or `Department`.